# Do routers verify UDP and TCP checksums?

Tags: routing

For some reason, I am having a super difficult time trying to Google the answer to this question, which seems very simple at the outset: Do routers in the networking stack verify UDP and TCP checksums, and drop the packet if it's incorrect? My understanding is that routers only consider checksums in the IP header, and UDP / TCP checksums are done at the endpoints, but I'm not 100% sure if that's correct.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: IP routing does not care about the encapsulated protocol. http://www.tcpipguide.com/

Comment: Are you asking what real world routers actually do? Or are you asking what is officially part of the definition of what a router does?

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Comment: @MadHatter. That was not helpful. This question is clear and there is no evidence that the author's claim to have looked around was false. Consider how many upvotes there are on the answer!

The actual answer is that the question is off-topic for this site.  This is a hobbyist question, not a professional network administration question.  Glad the asker got a good answer I could benefit from before the question was closed.

Comment: @JosiahYoder I don't necessarily disagree with anything you said, but **there's no reason to think it's my downvote**.  I'm simply pointing out, without prejudice, the system definition of a downvote; it's a standard-format answer that I posted a lot when I had any desire whatsoever to improve SF.  It's also eight years old, which is something you might want to take into account when deciding to cavil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: No

Longer answer: A router which implements just the router functionality does not and cannot verify UDP and TCP checksums. However routers do exist with additional functionality. If the router has NAT and/or firewall functionality, the answer may differ.

There are many reasons for a router not to verify the checksums:

- It would slow down packet processing.
- The router might not even know the higher level protocol and thus not know if it has a checksum and how to check it.
- It may be fragmented such that the checksum (which is only present in the first fragment) covers all packets.
- It add needless complexity which makes it harder to implement - in particular if you want a hardware implementation rather than a software implementation.

However if the router simultaneously implement NAT and/or a firewall, then it has to consider the higher level protocol. That eliminates one reason not to verify the checksum. If it mangles the packet (which NAT by definition does), then the transport layer checksum is no longer valid, so it has to be updated.

Updating the checksum can be done without verifying the old checksum or computing the new checksum from scratch. Instead the old checksum can be modified to only compensate for the changes made to the actual packet. This is possible due to the way the checksums work. Since the fields NAT need to mangle are in the same packet as the checksum, this makes it possible for NAT to mangle the packet and update the checksum without needing to fully reassemble the packets. (Unfortunately all the other fragments don't have the full information needed by the NAT to route the packet, so a NAT device still need to keep state about other fragments and in some cases buffer fragments until it knows where to send them.)

A firewall may want to perform inspections on the packet covering data across multiple fragments. If it is going to inspect the entire reassembled packet, then verifying the checksum as well is a good idea, otherwise invalid packets could be constructed which will pass validation in the firewall and then only need a single bitflip to turned into a malicious packet with a valid checksum. It would require a lot of luck to exploit, but nevertheless is worth protecting against if the firewall is going to reassemble the packet for inspection anyway. (Such a firewall might increase latency by buffering the packets, but it doesn't have to because it could forward all the packets except from the last such that a malicious packet discovered by the firewall could never be reassembled at the destination.)

There are other checksums which are indeed validated by routers. In IPv4 each packet has a header checksum which a router is supposed to validate before forwarding. Since the TTL field in the header has to be updated, the checksum also has to be updated at each hop.

In IPv6 the header checksum has been deemed unnecessary and was eliminated. The extra processing needed in routers was a concern, and with checksums in layers below and above IP having checksums covering the important fields in the IP header, it was not important. For this reason the checksum in UDP was made mandatory, in IPv4 the UDP checksum was optional.

If the lower layer is Ethernet it has packet checksums which are computed and verified on each hop along the path. Unlike the transport layer checksums the Ethernet layer checksums cover individual fragments.